# Effective ip->location query

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, local

I have two tables: one is ip_group_city from *ipinfodb.com* containing ip_start numbers for determining location of IPs, and other is "visits" with information about web site visitor containing column 'ip'.

I need to select top 10 region_code (from ip_group_city) by checking region_code for each IP from "visits" table.

Right now I'm loading all IPs from "visits" into an array and using that IP info to query the ip_group_city by:

```
SELECT region_code
FROM ip_group_city
WHERE ip_start <= INET_ATON(IP_FROM_ARR)
ORDER BY ip_start DESC LIMIT 1
```

I'm unable to create some sort of nested query to do the job for me, because right now things are a bit slow :) - it takes up to 30s on my laptop xampp (AMD Turion x2 2GHz, running windows 7 ultimate 64bit version)

Here's the table with IP addresses (visits)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visits` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`clientid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
`client_version` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=49272 ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you index "ip_start" field for improve performance?

Comment: Thx for your reply, but I'm afraid I don't know how to index that field :(

Comment: Also, advices on other ways around are accepted. Maybe there's some other db that's more effective for this king of job. I have more that 10.000 of IPs in the db that I need to solve for geolocation.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Using `ipinfodb_one_table_small` with MySQL 5.1, your query completes in under 10ms for me (on Linux). I assume the 30s are for doing multiple queries, e.g. for all visits. If so, please show the visits table also and how you loop over it.

Comment: ok, i'm adding the table structure to the question :)

Comment: btw, i managed to create solution that works in 6-9s using three files: one csv, that was used for data import, and two txt files that have only ip_start fields with locations in csv file where certain ip_numbers are (used for php _fseek_ function). 1st file has every 50th line from csv file, while second file has all the lines from csv file, but only with ip_start and position fields. i'm loading the first file into an array and then get info of 50 lines i need to load from 2nd file :). then again binary search and voilla :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said other solutions are welcomed...

You might want to check out [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location). They have good country and city lookups by IP. You can install an Apache or PHP plugin to make it fast - don't even have to handle the database yourself.

Answer (score 2):

To index your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `ip_group_city` ADD INDEX ( `ip_start` )
```

To get the top 10 region_codes:

```
SELECT igc.region_code
FROM ip_group_city igc
JOIN visits v ON igc.ip_start = v.ip
GROUP BY igc.region_code
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: unfortunately, v.ip is a string representing ip address, while ip_start is a number calculater by inet_aton function from ip address. Also, in the db there is 'only' 1.5Mil addresses, and those addresses cover basically all possible ips. your join would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `ip_group_city` ADD INDEX ( `ip_start` )
```

thats all i'm saying. be sure to use btree and not hash :D