# php file random access and object to file saving

Tags: php, file-io

I have a csv file with records being sorted on the **first field**. I managed to generate a function that does binary search through that file, using *fseek* for random access through file.

However, this is still a pretty slow process, since when I seek some file position, I actually need to look left, looking for \n characted, so I can make sure I'm reading a whole line (once whole line is read, I can check for first field value mentioned above).

Here is the function that returns a line that contains character at position *x*:

```
function fgetLineContaining( $fh, $x ) {
        if( $x  125145411) // 12514511 is the last pos in my file
            return "";
        // now go as much left as possible, until newline is found
        // or beginning of the file
        while( $x > 0 && $c != "\n" && $c != "\r") {
            fseek($fh, $x);
            $x--; // go left in the file
            $c =  fgetc( $fh );
        }
        $x+=2; // skip newline char
        fseek( $fh, $x );
        return fgets( $fh, 1024 ); // return the line from the beginning until \n
    }
```

While this is working as expected, I have to sad that my csv file has ~1.5Mil lines, and these left-seeks are slowing thins down pretty much.

Is there a better way to seek a line containing position *x* inside a file?

Also, it would be much better if object of a class could be saved to a file without serializing it, thus enabling reading of a file object-by-object. Does php support that?

Thanks

Comment: also, another idea came to my mind - how about sampling a file - taking one entry per 1000 entries from file and storing it into array. this would produce 1500 element array, which I could binary search, getting the rough approximation where the desired line is. i could then load that remaining 1000 elements and do a binary search on them. does that do the same thing?

Comment: What kind of searches are you performing on this file? Does the file change frequently? If you'll be performing many searches on the same file, it might be a lot faster to just load the data into an SQLite database and search the database.

Comment: If you know the length of an average line, you can just go back a bit and do `fgets()` to align the pointer with the end of the previous line, or a few lines before that. Should be good enough for the purpose of binary search.

Comment: If the file is static, you could write a one-off script to build an index of offset values for each x, that could be stored in a second fixed line size .idx file (simple math to fseek the position of the entry you need in the index) and use the stored entry as the fseek value to lookup the entry in your CSV file.

Comment: @mark: yes, it's a static file. great idea! I'll try that as well.
@kijin: i had it in mysql, but was unhappy with speed - i need to search it some 10.000 times

Comment: If you had it in MySQL before, and weren't happy with performance, any seeking in a csv is going to be a lot slower. A properly indexed MySQL table is always going to be faster than random file access.

Comment: hmmm ... well, the thing is this - this is geolocation db. the one on the country level is working much faster when results are loaded into an array than when they are in table (which is reasonable, considering that i need to repeat my query some 10 000 times).so i was thinking to load 1500 elements, on on each 1000 elements, and then from file only load 1000 element and search them. that could work maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really should consider using SQLite or MySQL again (like others have suggested in the comments). Most of the suggestions about pre-calculating indexes are already implemented "properly" in these SQL engines.

You said the speed wasn't good enough in SQL. Did you have the fields indexed properly? How were you querying the data? Where you using bulk queries, where you using prepared statements? Did the SQL process have enough ram to store it's indexes in RAM?

One thing you can possibly try to speed under the current algorithm is to load the (~100MB ?) file onto a RAM disc. No matter what you chose to do, either CVS or SQLite, this WILL help speed things up, especially if the hard drive seek time is your bottleneck.

You could possibly even read the whole file into PHP array's (assuming your computer has enough RAM for that). That would allow you to do your search via index (`$big_array[$offset]`) lookups.

Also one thing to keep in mind, PHP isn't exactly super fast at doing low level things fast. You might want to consider moving away from PHP in favor of C or C++.

Comment: Well, sql part of this question is located under bounty questions, at this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007671/effective-ip-location-query). I don't have experience in mysql optimization, and have to say I don't know an answer to all your questions.

Comment: i managed to get 3-4 times acceleration using 2 more aditional files with a sort-of binary search :)